# How to share Nuxt application country-specific links with vue-social-sharing package on Facebook?

Tags: nuxt.js

Nuxt Vue-Social-Sharing package

My Nuxt application has a header dropdown menu (has different country flags) that allows users to select a country according to their location and the application will load only information from that specific country. So the problem I'm facing is that when I share a link  of particular image and country on Facebook, the link doesn't return the country which I send the link from, it just returns the image and default country location

I'm using vue-social-sharing package on my nuxt application to share links (images) onto my Facebook page.

Is there a way of fixing this problem?